# How to set a limit for a switch to 0 of a variable for 2 variables combined

Tags: modeling, constraint

I have a follow up question to another question of mine [How to set a limit for a switch to 0 of a variable](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6127/how-to-set-a-limit-for-a-switch-to-0-of-a-variable) about counting the number of switches to 0 of one decision variable. Now I would like to ask the same question for two combined decision variables. So basically I have the decision variable x(t) and another decision variable y(t). The both quantify the heating output of a heating device for two different thermal storage systems for every timeslot t in [1,...,288]. It should be avoided that the heating device is switched on and off frequently thus I want to set a limit for the switching.

The rule in pseudocode looks like this:

```
if (x(t-1)>0 AND x(t)=0 AND y(t)=0) OR if (y(t-1)>0 AND y(t)=0 AND x(t)=0) 
then increase count by 1
Constraint: count <= limit
```

Both variables x(t) and y(t) are continious variables with the boundaries [0,1]. It should also be noted that x(t) and y(t) can't be greater 0 simultaneously (this would mean that the heating device would have heated up 2 storages at the same time which is not possible). For this I just use 2 constraints with binary auxilliary variable h(t)

```
x(t)<= h(t)
y(t)<= (1- h(t))
with h(t) in {0,1}
```

Any idea how I can derive constraints for something like this? Next to the pure answer I would also appreciate some general advices as how to approach questions like this (if there is a more or less general way of doing this).

Comment: Using your pseudocode, if $x(t-1)=1$ and $y(t)=1$ (so that one unit switches off at the same time the other switches on), the count is *not* incremented. Is that intentional?

Comment: Thanks prubin for your comment. Yes this is intentional. Basically - as mentioned in my description - we only have 1 heating unit that servers 2 storage systems. Switching between the 2 systems is not a problem if the device keeps running

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Again, you need to introduce binaries:

- $\delta_t$ takes values $1$ if and only if the device is switched off at time $t$
- $\alpha_t$ is the binary associated with variable $x_t$
- $\beta_t$ is the binary associated with variable $y_t$

The condition can be written in conjunctive normal form as follows:

$$ 
(\alpha_{t-1}\wedge \lnot \alpha_{t} \wedge \lnot \beta_{t}) \vee (\beta_{t-1}\wedge \lnot \beta_{t} \wedge \lnot \alpha_{t}) \implies \delta_t\\
\lnot \left( (\alpha_{t-1}\wedge \lnot \alpha_{t} \wedge \lnot \beta_{t}) \vee (\beta_{t-1}\wedge \lnot \beta_{t} \wedge \lnot \alpha_{t})\right) \vee \delta_t\\
 (\lnot \alpha_{t-1}\vee  \alpha_{t} \vee \beta_{t}) \wedge (\lnot \beta_{t-1}\vee  \beta_{t} \vee  \alpha_{t}) \vee \delta_t\\
(\lnot \alpha_{t-1}\vee  \alpha_{t} \vee \beta_{t} \vee \delta_t)\wedge (\lnot \beta_{t-1}\vee  \beta_{t} \vee  \alpha_{t} \vee \delta_t)\\
(1-\alpha_{t-1}+\alpha_t + \beta_t+ \delta_t \ge 1) \wedge (1-\beta_{t-1}+\beta_t + \alpha_t+ \delta_t \ge 1) 
$$

And since $x_t$ and $y_t$ cannot simultaneously be positive, the constraints are
\begin{align}
 \alpha_{t-1} &\le  \alpha_t + \beta_t+ \delta_t \quad &\forall t   \tag{1}\\ 
  \beta_{t-1} &\le \beta_t + \alpha_t+ \delta_t \quad &\forall t \tag{2}\\
\sum_t \delta_t &\le \ell \tag{3} \\
\alpha_t + \beta_t &\le 1 \quad &\forall t \tag{4} \\
x_t &\le M \alpha_t  \quad &\forall t \tag{5} \\
y_t &\le M \beta_t  \quad &\forall t \tag{6} \\
\end{align}

Comment: +1 for CNF. Because of the fourth constraint, you can strengthen the formulation by merging the first two constraints as $\alpha_{t-1}+\beta_{t-1}\le\alpha_t+\beta_t+\delta_t$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kuifje and RobPratt for your answer. @Kuifje: I do not understand the tranission from the 1. line to the 2. line in your conjunctive normal form and I do not understand the transission from the 4. line to the 5. line.

Comment: @RobPratt: I do not understand how and why you strenghten the constraints? It this necessary? Otherwise I would not do it

Comment: @PeterBe you can [check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_implication) that the truth table of the implication $A \Rightarrow B$ is the same as $\lnot A \vee B$. And for the last line, if a logical statement is true then its binary variable is $\ge 1$.

Comment: Thanks Kuifje for your comment and effort. Regarding the Line 1 to 2: I do not understand why "A-->B" is the same as "not A or B"? Let's say A: "The sun is shining" and B: "I go to the sea". So "A-->B" means, if the sun is shining, I go to the sea. How would you read  "not A or B"? Either the sun is not shining or I go to the sea? This does not make much sense according to my point of view. 
Regarding Line 4 to 5: Why and how do you change they AND-symbol to an OR-symbol in the middle. And why do you add two times the 1 in each bracket? Regarding the comment: it's okay. I gave an answer

Comment: Please refer to [conditional operators](https://medium.com/i-math/intro-to-truth-tables-boolean-algebra-73b331dd9b94). For the last line it was a typo, thanks for noting.

Comment: Thanks Kuifje. Regarding Line 1 to 2: I read your link and I understand the truth tables. However, I do not comprehend the transission logically. Let's take my example again. A: "The sun is shining" and B: "I go to the sea".  How would you read  "not A or B" and why is this logically (intuitively) equivalent to "A-->B"? Would you mind elaborating a little bit on that? Regarding the last line: I also had a second question in my last comment "why do you add two times the 1 in each bracket?". The right >=1 is because the logical bracket should be true. But where does the left 1 come from

Comment: To be honest I am not really sure there is an intuition behind the equivalence of the two truth tables. Maybe @RobPratt can give you more insight on this intuition? The left $1$ comes from the fact that $\lnot \alpha$ is equivalent to $1-\alpha$. And also, I would rather let Rob answer the part about his strengthened constraints but a short answer is 1) it is not necessary, it will only potentially speed up the computation time 2) it is derived from the fact that $\alpha_{t-1}+\beta_{t-1} \le 1$

Comment: Regarding the intuition of $P \implies Q$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011842/without-truth-tables-how-can-you-intuit-that-p-implies-q-equiv-lnot-p.  Regarding the strengthening, it is not necessary but when you can simultaneously shrink and strengthen a formulation, it is almost always a good idea to do so: less memory, faster LP solves, less branching, etc.

Comment: Thanks RobPratt for your answer. I still do not understand how you merge the constraints. Would you mind elaborating a little bit more on that? Your merged constraint is equal ot the first constraint of Kuifje except that you add 'Beta (t-1)' additionally to the left side. Why are you allowed to do that?

Comment: @PeterBe It is a "clique lifting": if $x_i$ is binary and $x_i + \sum_j a_j y_j \le b$ for all $i$ and $\sum_i x_i \le 1$, then you can strengthen to $\sum_i x_i + \sum_j a_j y_j \le b$.

Comment: As a complement to Rob's answer, convince yourself by checking that the constraint holds for the three possible cases $(\alpha_{t-1},\beta_{t-1}) \in \{ (0,0),(0,1),(1,0)\}$

Comment: Thanks for your comment @RobPratt and Kuifje. I have to admit that I still not not understand it and I have several questions. 1) x (t) is not a binary but a continuous variable. 2) Why is x (i) + sum (alpha (j), y (j)<= b? 3) What is the index i in the sum (x(i))<=1 and why is it <=1? x can be between 0 and 1 for every timeslot. So the sum over all timeslots t is not <=1. Even if x (i) was a binary, the sum over all i would not be <=1.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  My $x_i$ is a different variable than your $x(t)$.  I'll open a separate question and answer it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort RobPratt. I saw you quesiton (and answer) but I still have problems mapping them to my examples. What are the x(i) in my case and where is the constraint that sum of all x(i) <= 1 in my case? I do not have any constraint with a sum (except the limiation constraint numer (3)).

Comment: You can map as follows: his $x_1$ is your $\alpha_{t-1}$ and his $x_2$ is your $\beta_{t-1}$. So his $\sum_i x_i = x_1+x_2 \le 1$ is your $\alpha_{t-1} + \beta_{t-1} \le 1$. And his $-\sum_j a_j y_j$ is your $\beta_t + \alpha_t + \delta_t$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Kuifje. Why is his - sum (a(j)*y(j)) my  beta (t) + alpha (t) + delta (t)?

Comment: Any comments to my last comment? I'd highly appreciate every further comment.

Comment: Rewrite the constraint like this $\alpha_{t-1} +(-\alpha_t - \beta_t- \delta_t)  \le 0  $, this way you can identify it to $x_1 + (a_1y_1+a_2y_2 +a_3y_3) \le b $. And btw, if you are happy with the answer to the initial question, feel free to accept the answer ;)

Comment: Do I still need the 3 constraints when using the reduction approach from RobPratt (constraint 1,2 and 4) or is just the one equation enough posted by RobPratt "αt−1+βt−1≤αt+βt+δt"?

Comment: I accepted and upvoted your answer Kuifje. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: No problem. You can use RobPratt's constraint without the initial ones.But you do need to keep constraint $(4)$. Just omit $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: I just found a small mistake. You write that the equations should be valid for all t However when using a difference equation Beta(t-1) then you can't use it for t=1 as Beta(1-1) = Beta(0) is undefined becaue t begins with 1 and not with 0.

Comment: And I have another question to your suggsted equations 5 and 6. Why do I need the Big-M here and can I not just get rid of it?

Comment: @Kuifje: Any comments to my last 2 comments and questions? I'd highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: You can initialize $\beta_0$ with the correct value. You need the big-M constraints, in order to link the continuous and binary variables.

Comment: Thanks Kuifje for your answer. Here in this quesiton https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6127/how-to-set-a-limit-for-a-switch-to-0-of-a-variable you do not use the big-M to link the continuous and the binary variable (see your EDIT). Why is this case different?

Comment: And I still generally do not understand why I need the big-M here. Why do I need it for linking the continuous and binary variables? If alpha has the value 1 then x can have all the values up to 1 and if alpha has the value 0, x will be 0. So why do I need to multiply a big-M here?

Comment: In this case $M:=1$

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks Kuifje. I still have a problem understanding the linking that I wrote in the other question https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6127/how-to-set-a-limit-for-a-switch-to-0-of-a-variable

Comment: @Kuifje: Are you sure that the linking of the binary and the continous variable is correct? I somehow doubt it. When x(t) has the value 0 then alpha (t) can still take the value 1 as far as I see it by using your suggested equations. Or is there anything that I miss? What probibits alpha(t) to the the value 1 if x(t) has the value 0?

Comment: Yes, same as in your other question, you might want to enfore $x_t=0 \; \Rightarrow \; \alpha_t = 0$ to prevent $\alpha_t$ from taking value $1$.

Comment: @Kuifje: Thanks for your answer. But how can I create equations that ensure that if x (t) =0, alpha (t) =0? Your suggested equations do not do that.

Comment: Indeed, you will have to refer to the other question you posted, once it gets an answer.