# How to couple a binary variable to a continuous variable to indicate values greater 0

Tags: constraint, binary-variable, indicator-constraints

I have a continuous variable $x_t$. A binary variable $b_t$ should be coupled to $x_t$ such that $b_t$ has the value $1$ if $x_t$ has a value greater than $0$ and $b_t$ has the value $0$ if $x_t$ has the value $0$. Any idea how I can do that without including the term $b_t$ in the objective function?

Comment: This is a FAQ -- frequently asked here and frequently answered here.

Comment: You will have to choose a tolerance as to how close to zero should be considered zero, taking into account solver tolerance, wherein a variable for which the true optimum is exactly zero will not be exactly zero as computed in and returned by the solver.

Comment: @prubin I agree this is a FAQ, [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/33/in-an-integer-program-how-i-can-force-a-binary-variable-to-equal-1-if-some-cond?rq=1) is quite a complete answer. But it may be worth answering $x_t=0\; \Rightarrow \; b_t = 0$ (?), which is the hard part, I think.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thanks for your answer Mark L. Stone. How can I formulate this with equations?

Comment: @prubin: Thanks for your comment. Would you mind sending me 2 or 3 links to such questions? I'd highly apprciate this.

Comment: @Kuifje: Thanks for the link. I think that the answer there does not quite answer my question. There it is stated for continous variables there are 2 cases: Case 1 "if x>b then y=1" --> this also holds for my example and is in line with what I want. In my case b is just 0. However, the Case 2: "if x=b then y=1" is not in line with what I want. if x=b (and b is 0 in my case) then y should be also 0.  Any idea how I can formulate this with equations?

Comment: @PeterBe Try typing "binary variable continuous variable" in the search box. Not all hits are relevant, but it is easy to find some that are.

Comment: @prubin: Thanks for your answer. I searched for it but I could not find a question that exactly answered my question. The answers that I found are either wrong or they deal with another case

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, Kuifje : Do yo have any idea how I can link those variables? I'd appreciate every further comments from you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm only aware of a mechanism that works if there is an upper bound for the continuous variable.

\begin{align}x_{t, \max}\cdot b_t &\geq x_t\\ m\cdot x_t &\geq b_t\end{align}

I used this in answering [this question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6200/assignment-and-scheduling-problem-with-resource-constraints/6236?noredirect=1#comment11082_6236). I'm not aware of a way to solve it for unbounded $x_t$, unless the solver handles floating points infinities correctly. This would need to be tested by solvers.
The second equation implements the $x_t < \frac{1}{m}\implies b_t=0 $. If the trueness of $b_t$ is penalized in the objective the second term is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks worldsmithhelper for your answer. Basically the continous variable has an upper bound of 1 and a lower bound of 0. Nonetheless I think your approach does not work and is wrong. If x(t) has the value 0.2, then your second equations forces b(t) to have the value 0 which is wrong.

Comment: Mhh you are right. You could fix that by multiplying $x_t$ by a sufficiently large numbers. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort worldsmithhelper. This solution might work. I will try it. How would your suggested solution change, if the lower bound of x is let's say 0.25 (while the upper bounds remains 1)?

Comment: $x_{t,max} = 1$ and $m=4$

Comment: Thanks worldsmithhelper  for your answer. I upvoted and accepted your answer. I really appreciate your tremendous help.

Answer (score 4):

Enforcing $b_t$ to take value $1$ when $x_t$ is positive is done with $x_t \le b_t$, assuming $x_t \le 1$.

For the second part, quoting @MarkL.Stone:

> You will have to choose a tolerance as to how close to zero should be
> considered zero

Let $\epsilon$ be this tolerance. So you want to enforce
$$
x_t < \epsilon\implies b_t = 0
$$

Now referring to [this link](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/33/in-an-integer-program-how-i-can-force-a-binary-variable-to-equal-1-if-some-cond?rq=1) (careful as $b$ in the link is a constant $\neq$ your $b_t$):

> *To enforce "if $x < b$ then $y=1$"*:  $$b - x \le My,$$ where $M$ is a large constant. The logic is that if $b - x > 0$, then $y$ must
> equal 1, and otherwise it may equal 0.

Given that $x_t \le 1$, and that you want the binary variable to take value $0$ (and not $1$), the constraint becomes:
$$
\epsilon-x_t \le 1-b_t
$$

It is easy to see that if $b_t$ takes value $1$, then it implies $x_t \ge \epsilon$, which is the contrapositive of what you want.

Comment: Thanks Kuifje for your answer (I upvoted it). The shorter (and simpler) answer given by worldsmithhelper seems to work. I have implement it and not experienced any problems so far. Do you see any problems with that answer?

Comment: Both approaches are similar and deal with a tolerance ($\epsilon$ or $1/m$), but the way the tolerance is handled is a bit different.

Comment: I would say try both and reward the one giving you better performance in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Many solvers and APIs allow logical constraints.

For instance with OPL CPLEX you may write

```
dvar float+ x;
dvar boolean b;

subject to
{
  
  b==!(x==0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answerAlex How can I formulate this with equations? I do not use OPL CPLEX and I would like to have an answer that is independent from the modelling language and the solver.

Comment: Then see https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/33/in-an-integer-program-how-i-can-force-a-binary-variable-to-equal-1-if-some-cond?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the link Alex. I think that the answer there does not quite answer my question. There it is stated for continous variables that there are 2 cases: Case 1 "if x>b then y=1" --> this also holds for my example and is in line with what I want. In my case b is just 0. However, the Case 2: "if x=b then y=1" is not in line with what I want. if x=b (and b is 0 in my case) then y should be also 0.  Any idea how I can formulate this with equations?